# How to debug unattended installation of MS SQL Server 2012?

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server, unattended, sql-server-2012

How can I *diagnose and debug a configuration file* for an unattended installation of MS SQL Server 2012?

**What I'm doing** --
I'm building an installer for a product. The product requires MS SQL Server 2012, which I want to install in an automated fashion. I know I can use a config file to do this, and it seems to accept the file (based on the "defaults" I'm seeing in the installer). However...

When I set: `QUIET="True"` or `QUIETSIMPLE="True"` then the installation takes *way* too little time -- in fact, it's not installing. It does go through the initial steps of decompressing the installer, but from then it just exits.

I'm thinking there must be an error in the config file (I have two versions: one I captured from a manual run-through, and one I've snipped off the Internet).

**What I've tried** -- I've tried capturing the error output, and the exit code, but there aren't any. I've also tried taking only a few of the options, but that produces no tangible difference.

The documentation mentions that a log file is created in `C:\Program Files\MS SQL Server\yadda yadda`, but I don't even have that folder so I really don't know where to look for evidence of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have contracted partial blindness. The log file *did* exist, at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt`, and it did state an error:

```
Overall summary:
Final result:                  Failed: see details below
Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578304
Exit facility code:            1204
Exit error code:               8
Exit message:                  The instance name must not contain spaces or special characters.
```

I've now updated my install script to parse this file after the installer finishes, and return this status.